# alter view in SQL DB2, adding new column

Tags: sql, view, db2, alter

I have created a view orderedView by ordering by series and values looking like this:

```
series | values  
     1 | 1  
     1 | 3  
     1 | 5  
     1 | 6  
     2 | -1  
     2 | 0  
     2 | 4  
     2 | 5
```

Now I would like to add a third column to my view, that enumerates each set of series from 1 to the end, like

```
series | values  | row_ID  
     1 |    1    | 1  
     1 |    3    | 2  
     1 |    5    | 3  
     1 |    6    | 4  
     2 |    3    | 1  
     2 |    6    | 2  
     2 |    8    | 3  
     2 |    9    | 4
```

I tried with

```
ALTER VIEW orderedView
    ADD COLUMN ROW_ID INT NOT NULL;
```

but intelliJ says after ALTER VIEW orderedView  "ALTER, DISABLE or ENABLE expected, got 'ADD'"

Is it even possible to alter my view by adding a new column or do I have to add the column before creating the view? And if so, how to do that?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: here is first google result : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_alterview.html

Comment: To change a view definition (for example, to add additional columns), you must drop the view and create a new view using the CREATE VIEW statement.

Comment: Well that doesn't really help me since i want to expand the view by a column that didn't exist before in the table, the view was retrieved from. Even if i drop the view and try ALTER VIEW orderedView ADD COLUMN ROW_ID INT NOT NULL; i have the same error.

Comment: Why would you drop the view and instead of using CREATE use ALTER command for recreation? Simply recreate view with all three columns. Can you paste the "create ddl" and error associated with it?

Comment: Thats what I tried with ALTER VIEW orderedView ADD COLUMN ROW_ID INT NOT NULL; at first, but didn't work. What would be the correct syntax to add a new column that did not exist before? Btw there is a typo in the second altered table, the value where series = 2 and  row_id = 1 should be -1 as in the first table.

Comment: I first wanted to add a column like here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/t0020132.html to my view (instead of to my original table) and after that fill in the row_id's as in my example. I think it is clear what I mean if you have a look at my example tables. And again, the row_ID column did not exist before in the original table the view was retrieved from.

Answer (score 1):

You must drop and recreate your view. A view is a query, your must then modified this query...

Comment: Alright thanks, well than it would be nice if someone could help me with creating a new view while adding and filling in the ROW_IDs. I now have this: CREATE VIEW orderedView AS (
  SELECT SERIES, VALUES, ROW_ID
  FROM originalTable
  ORDER BY SERIES, VALUES
); But still all my ROW_ID entries are null.

Comment: ROW_ID  is null into your originalTable, update your originalTable

Comment: Be warned, due to this limitation of not being able to alter an existing view in DB2, all other views derived from that view will also disappear (tested this on IBMi DB2). Not developer friendly at all. This is easily done in Microsoft SQL Server.